# PHP SESSION handling - invalid values

Tags: php, validation, session

We need to make use of session_write_close() inside a lot of existing codes. But this looks dangerous to us, because PHP does the following - without giving any warning or error:

```
session_name('goodoldasdf');
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['var'])) {
print ' Session-Data: '. $_SESSION['var'];
}

$_SESSION['var'] = "before";

session_write_close();

$_SESSION['var'] = "after"; // notice: definition after write close!

print ' B: '. $_SESSION['var'];
```

When we define a SESSION-var after session_write_close, PHP won't write the SESSION into MemcacheD session handler (as expected) - but it still use the overwrite inside the same script runtime.

> Output: " Pseudo-Session-Data: **after**".

second run:

> Output: " Session-Data: **before** Pseudo-Session-Data: **after**"

The question is: **How to make sure, that PHP is not using *pseudo* SESSION-vars, that are not actually written into the sessions?** Is there a way to get PHP warnings here? Or any suggestions to handle this issue?

---

**Why we need to add the write close everywhere:** After updating "PHP 5.x" to "PHP 7" everything slows down. Notably on AJAX-requests or simultaneous loading mutli-tabs. It's because PHP 7 seems to change it's SESSION-handling / blocking.

Very good demo: https://demo.ma.ttias.be/demo-php-blocking-sessions/

So we need to add session_write_close to a lot of scripts - without risking invalid sessions-values.

Comment: So use a non-blocking handler with optimistic locking.

Comment: got some more informations about it?

Comment: There is a non-blocking handler included here (in a framework that you can use to add storage substrates and the the the optimistic locking as desperate concerns) https://www.phpclasses.org/package/9455-PHP-Store-session-data-with-multiple-session-handlers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the output of `session_status()` ([Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php))

```
switch(session_status()) {
    case PHP_SESSION_DISABLED:
        die('Sessions disabled on this server');
    case PHP_SESSION_NONE:
        die('Session has not been started, or has been closed');
    case PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE:
        die('There is currently an active session');
}
```

You can utilise this with a wrapper function for getting / setting session variables.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Checking the session_status everytime before writing to SESSION seems laborious. I'm wondering if PHP got any global error handling on this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `session_write_close();` write your own function and unset the superglobal:

```
function session_stop() {
    session_write_close();
    unset($_SESSION);
}
```

Now you will get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in file X line Y

Comment: You would also not be able to read the session-data anymore, aren't you?